# How to set the first letter in a line to caps in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to set the first letter in each line to caps in notepad++..how do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could select the block consisting of only the first column: hold `Alt` while selecting with the mouse. Then press `Ctrl-Shift-U` to convert the selected letters to uppercase.

This kind of selection is called *rectangular selection* in the Notepad++ help. You can also define the selection with the keyboard by pressing `Alt` and `Shift` and using the cursor keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for an larger document, the solution of @Andre doesn't seem suitable. Instead you can use regex. Make sure, the regex option in the search dialog is set, search for `^([a-z])` and replace with `\u$1`.