# Notepad++: Capitalize first letter by Shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-files, notepad++, notepad, capitalization

I've got a huge list of words (every single word in one line in a txt file) and certain words need to get capitalized manually (e.g. by hand), so I was looking if there's a shortcut in notepad++ (my editor currently) to automatically capitalize the first letter of a line but couldnt find one. Is there none? If not, can you advise me an alternative windows program to quickly do this by using a simple shortcut (so I can go through with the arrow-down key and use the shortcut whenever needed on a specific word)?
thanks a lot

Comment: This might help: http://superuser.com/questions/223016/can-i-search-and-replace-in-a-notepad-macro

Comment: Actually not, but I did it myself yesterday whcich took me like 2 hours, but nevermind...

Comment: Q: What was your solution?  Q: Are you pleased with the solution, and the fact that it only took two hours?  Q: If not, had you considered writing an awk script, or a Perl or Java program instead of using Notepad++?

Comment: I did it manually, so I wasnt pleased but couldnt see an alternative since there's no shortcut for it...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This can be easily done if the first letters are latin characters. But this method does not work with non-latin (for example cyrillic) characters. Just press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**, enable "Regular Expression" checkbox, and search for

```
^(.)
```

replace with (Replace All)

```
\u\1
```

". matches newline" checkbox has to be unchecked

Comment: Genius. +1.  What does that replacement pattern mean in English?

Comment: That means "find any symbol /./ at the beginning of each line /^/, place it in the first group /parentheses - ()/ and replace the first group /\1/ with the same uppercase symbol /\u/".

Comment: Wow.  I use a lot of regex, but I didn't know that one. Thanks!

Comment: Seems it doesn't work in Notepad++ v5.8.7 - it just places "\u" on the beginning of each line. Update: found alternate solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/9869702/1427210

Comment: To replace it should be `Ctrl` + `H`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: if anyone looking for converting first letter to lowercase then use -  \l\1 (lowercase L followed by number 1) instead of \u\1

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can install  the TextFX plugin and apply Sentense case.
Here you have some tricks (including this one).
http://a4apphack.com/featured/tricks-with-notepad

Comment: TextFX is the easiest solution IMHO. After installing the plugin, simply select all relevant text and then navigate to `TextFX > TextFX Characters > Sentence case`

Comment: I was looking for "Proper Case", I forgot it was in there

Answer (score 7):

For those who have hard time following textual instructions, here is the screenshot. (answer credit to @Placido)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Enable Column Mode in N++ and then select the first column. change case to upper  case.

Comment: Your answer is a bit vague. You've not said *how* to select a column, or *how* to change the case of the selection.

Comment: To use column mode, place the cursor where you want to start, hold the alt key, and drag. Or press alt-shift-arrow (didn't try that way).  Not useful for the OP it sounds like, but worked for me.

Comment: I will upvote you answer (+1) because it helped me but WaiHaLee is right, you SHOULD explain HOW to enter column mode and HOW to select the first column (you still can do it by editing your answer, do it!). Thanks @nasch.

Answer (score 3):

There is a shortcut available in Notepad++ v7.3.2 to capitalize only the first letter of the selected text:

ALT + CTRL + U

Not sure about prior versions.

Comment: I selected the whole text and pressed the shortcut but only the first line was capitalised. However, it's an interesting shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly select the text and use **ALT+U** shortcut

Comment: Doesnt work for me, maybe you have some sort of plugin installed... Base Notepad++ Installation => not possible :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open you file in notepad++
2. Hit ctrl + F
3. Click on Replace tab
4. Put \n[the letter you wanna capitalize] inside "Find what" field
5. Put \n[the letter capitalized] inside the "Replace with" field
6. Set the search mode to "Extended"
7. Hit Replace All button

This will capitalize every first letter of a line.
You can modify this method to capitalize under other conditions

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was looking for. Every word is different and I need to look at it to see if it needs to get capitalized (thus scrolling down the list via the arrow down key) and if so, than I want to quickly do this for this line....

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quick in an unortodox way, but you'll need TotalCommander.

Create new file with a name containing text you want to capitalize.
Select this file in TotalCommander.
Press Ctrl+M (Multirename Tool).
In "Uppercase/Lowercase" dropdown select "First of each word uppercase".

Under Windows.
There is a draw back: filename limits to 255 characters if i'm not mistaken.
And some special characters will be ommited (slashes, double quote, etc).

Also similar software like Far should work in the same way I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quickly in MS Word by highliting the list and then using shift + f3
This will cycle through all-upper, all-lower or first letter caps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recording a macro and then assigning it to a shortcut?

e.g. Your replacement could be:

```
Find what:    (\A|[.!?]\s+)(\w+)
Replace with: $1\u$2

Tick 'In selection'
```

And then navigate to `Macro` → `Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro...` in the top menu and assign a shortcut.

---

This is the resulting macro that I extracted from `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`.

It uses the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

```
<Macro name="Capitalise" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="67">
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="(\A|[.!?]\s+)(\w+)" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="$1\u$2" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="896" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

Answer (score 1):

first you select the first column by pressing alt+ctrl+shift.
After seletion just press ctrl+U keys
Problem solved